# how to get old and new values of modified entity : Telerik Open DataAccess

Tags: winforms, telerik, entity-framework-6, telerik-open-access

I am using Telerik Entity framework, I was looking for some method / function by means of which i can get new (current) values of a modified entity,

as i already can get old values of modified entity by doing this...

```
IEnumerable<string> modifiedFields = _context.GetMemberNames(_​entityName, Telerik.OpenAccess.ObjectState.Dirty);
foreach (var array in modifiedFields)
     MessageBox.Show("OLD = " + _context.GetOriginalValue<string>(_entityName, array) );
```

how to get new values, any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Following extension method returns new value from the entity object in Telerik Data Access

```
_entityName.FieldValue<string>(nameOfPersistentField)
```

> Returns the value of the named persistent field of the given persistent instance.